# Define vs namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, macros, typedef

I have a code:

```
namespace My
{
    #define sptr std::shared_ptr;
}
```

It was used in a lot of places. Now I've included this code as library into qt project and it failed to load because somewhere it uses `sptr` as variable name.

I can modify Qt header and rename variable but this isn't good in portability side. What is the best way to solve this problem? `typedef` can't be used with templates. I know hack with templated structure but I still have to modify my code with it.

Comment: Preprocessor directives are not subject to namespaces.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I know that. Now it brought me described problem.

Comment: `auto p = std::make_shared<Foo>();`. With C++11, the times where you want to say "shared_ptr" explicitly should be fairly rare.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, thanks, I know it. But for now it requires to rewrite my code. And I don't have time for this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
namespace ns {
  template<typename T>
  using sptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
}
```

See also @Kerrek SB's comment to the question regarding this specific use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
  template<typename T>
  struct sptr : std::shared_ptr<T> { };
```

This is a simple wrapper around the `std::shared_ptr`. This will work both in C++2003 and C++11.

Comment: Your code will certainly work, but without further work for example `sptr<int>(new int)` won't.